# How to create different colours for the same group between geom_smooth and geom_point?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to have to colours in the same same group. It would also be nice to select line type.

I would like the colour to be a bit different in the same group in geom_point for a given line type than the points plotted with geom_point. I would like to have the line for a given given group be different from the points. How would I go about doing this?

I have created some sample data.

Note: I'm getting errors when I try to use linetype in geom_smooth().

```
#test data
obs=rep(1:3, each=30)
length(obs)
set.seed(50)
x=sample(seq(from = 20, to = 50, by = 5), size = 90, replace = TRUE)
y=sample(seq(from = 200, to = 500, by = 5), size = 90, replace = TRUE)

df = data.frame(obs,x,y)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = factor(obs)))+
geom_point()+
theme(legend.position="bottom")+
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 50, by = 4),expand = c(0, 0), labels = comma_format())+
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 500, by = 10),limits = c(0, 500),expand = c(0, 0), labels = comma_format())+
geom_smooth(aes(group=obs), method="lm")+
scale_colour_manual(values = c("wheat3", "slategray1","dimgray"),name = "Average Density Band:")
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I would like to have the line for a given given group be different from the points.

Comment: You can use `geom_line(aes(x,y,linetype=factor(obs)),data=df)` to add line for a given group and can use `scale_linetype_manual` to change linetypes. I don't understand how does that `comma_format()` work. Does it require a package ?

Comment: Yes for comma_format() is in the package library(scales)

Comment: I believe I might not be able to make R create a chart like the one I want. I was trying to plot a regression line a different colour than than the group of data points it was based on. when I use scale_colour_manual() it is applied too all points/lines based on the given group. i.e. if I set group one colour to be blue then both the regression line and the points based on group one are blue. I would like the line say black and the points blue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a particularly good idea as you lose a visual clue as to what points are connected to what regression line, however the following does work for me. Essentially I took the colour aesthetic out of the `ggplot()` call and pass it to `geom_point()` and `geom_smooth()` individually.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
#test data
obs=rep(1:3, each=30)
length(obs)
set.seed(50)
x=sample(seq(from = 20, to = 50, by = 5), size = 90, replace = TRUE)
y=sample(seq(from = 200, to = 500, by = 5), size = 90, replace = TRUE)

df = data.frame(obs,x,y)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y))+
geom_point(color = factor(obs))+
theme(legend.position="bottom")+
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 50, by = 4),expand = c(0, 0), labels = comma_format())+
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 500, by = 10),limits = c(0, 500),expand = c(0, 0), labels = comma_format())+
geom_smooth(aes(group=obs, color = factor(obs)), method="lm")+
scale_colour_manual(values = c("orange", "yellow","blue"),name = "Average Density Band:")
```

I changed your line colours as I couldn't see them with my eyesight.
I suspect this isn't meant to work like this and to be frank I'm not 100% sure as to why it does.